# What is Allelic Imbalance

Tags: phylogenetics

Can anyone help me explain what allelic imbalance is, hopefully shortly? 
Surprisingly, we cannot find any introduction online.

Comment: Some more context would help. Where did you see the term? Is it with respect to a phenotype? A gene? A population? An individual?

Comment: You may also consider looking into allele-specific expression. That may turn up more information on allelic imbalance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be used differently in different contexts, but generally speaking, in my world - allelic imbalance is when there's a difference in the level of gene expression from different alleles, usually through genetic (e.g. a variant in a promoter) or epigenetic mechanisms (e.g. one copy silenced, as in imprinted regions).

There are a [few](http://nathansheffield.com/wordpress/what-is-allelic-imbalance/) [blog](https://www.rna-seqblog.com/direct-testing-for-allele-specific-expression-differences-between-conditions/) posts here with some more information, and plenty of papers (google "Allelic imbalance") if you want to dig deeper.